# OCaml User Defined Type Pattern Matching

Tags: ocaml, user-defined-functions

If I create my own type, for example:

```
type mynew =
 | Base
 | Co of mynew
 | Io of mynew
```

How do I access/deconstruct this type with pattern matching? So that, if I have IO(CO(IO(BASE))) I can pass it as a value to a function and access the first part (IO) and the tail (CO(IO(BASE)))?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to apply pattern matching:

```
match yourParam with 
    Base -> (**) 
    | Co(t) -> (*Something with t*) 
    | Io(t) -> (*Something with t*)
```

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't find good documentation on it, this is helpful.

Comment: Just Google "pattern matching with recursive types", you'll find enough resources

Comment: Real World OCaml has a great example of that [here](https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/variants.html#variants-and-recursive-data-structures).